# Formik reset form, not to the initial state but a new one

Tags: reactjs, formik

So I am using formik for an update/edit form with the starting initial values as the current text. When I submit and call resetForm, the new text gets replaced with the past text.

```
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ text: existingPost.text }}
      onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
        exampleSubmitHanlder(values);
        actions.resetForm();
      }}>
```

I have something like that, and also tried doing `actions.resetForm({text: ''})` but this is not working as well

Answer (score 5):

I also needed this. The `resetForm` option will not work as this will always use the original `initialValues`.

Formik provides an [`enableReinitialize`](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean) prop:

> **enableReinitialize?: boolean**
>
> Default is `false`. Control whether Formik should reset the form if
> initialValues changes (using deep equality).

This option should work for you if after submitting, the `initialValues` are updated to the current state.

Example:

```js
<Formik
  enableReinitialize
  initialValues={{ text: existingPost.text }}
  onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
    // updates existingPost prop
    exampleSubmitHanlder(values);
}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

`resetForm` will reset your form values to the initial values passed to `Formik` component. If your initial values are not empty then in order to clear the values on submit, you can use `action.setValues({ text: '' })`.